# Chromium/PyQt5 support for MP4

Tags: qt, pyqt, chromium, qtwebengine

How can I get Chromium (QtWebEngine) to play MP4 and mpeg audio? For instance, SoundCloud or Pandora. When I try to use either of these applications I see this inside the console of QtWebEngine:

[image]

I have tried setting the Request Headers `Accept` and `Content-Type` to `audio/mp4` to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: As [per the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html#audio-and-video-codecs), qt must be built with proprietary codec support.

Comment: @ekhumoro Ok yes I see that now. How can I incorporate a custom build with PyQt5? Currently I just have it installed through Python's package manager

Comment: You would have to rebuild qt, and then [rebuild pyqt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#building-and-installing-from-source) (making sure you specified the rebuilt qt in the config options).

Comment: For rebuilding PyQt5, can I add the customized Qt5's qmake.exe to `PATH`, and then run `pip install PyQt5`? Will this pick up the customized Qt5's features like the proprietary codecs? Or do I need to do any other configurations? I couldn't really follow the documentation link that you added. Thanks

Comment: @SamG101 you gotta build it via the SIP cli (with your custom qmake.exe in the PATH, or set explicitly `sip-install --qmake <your_path>`). ekhumoro's link helped me out with this